# Testcafe not loading page completely - iframe parts missing

Tags: testing, iframe, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have a internal page which contain a header and then a part where some news content is shown.
The header part is found under <.body class...><.div class...><.table ...> and that is a part that is shown.
The news flow content is found under <.body class...><.table id = "iframe">.

The problem I have is that the content in the table iframe is empty when run via testcafe. There is more or less nothing else in that iframe than some testcafe references like:

<.script type="text/javascript" class="script-hammerhead-shadow-ui" charset="UTF-8" src="http://172.30.48.47:49788/hammerhead.js">
<.script type="text/javascript" class="script-hammerhead-shadow-ui" charset="UTF-8" src="http://172.30.48.47:49788/testcafe-core.js">

Any ideas on what I can do to make the iframe content to load when running via TestCafe?

Comment: Would you please open a browser console and check if there are any errors there? Press F12 to open the console.

Comment: Hi Marion. I don´t see any errors. The `<body>` part is empty.
`<body></body>` == $0
 `</html>`
 `</iframe>`

Comment: Would you please provide me with the following information for research?
- A screenshot of the browser console; - Your page rendering with TestCafe and without TestCafe.